# Procedural Island Generation confusion

Tags: python, numpy, procedural-generation

So I've been working on a terragen for a sort of survival RTS game. Up until now I've been using radial island generation (basically it creates a somewhat circular island shape). I found this to be uninteresting, so developed a fractal island generator that generates (I believe, anyway) better and more varied island shapes.

Here are a few islands I made using this method:

[image]

It works by making a quadrilateral and subdividing recursively until the required level of detail is reached.
To create the island overlay, I need to fill this outline with white. My initial plan acted like a paint bucket tool and operated from pixels. I found this to be too slow for my liking, so developed a line intersection method. Problem with this method is that I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

It operates (or at least is meant to) by inverting the colour of the pixels in a horizontal line every time that line intersects with the shape. Thusly it fills the shapes.

Example images of the issue:

[image]

```
def invertFill(shape, res):
invertMap = numpy.zeros((res,res), dtype=bool)
#loop through outline vectors, find intersect points
for n in range(len(shape)):#loop through outline vectors
    if n == len(shape) - 1:
        nPlus = 0
    else:
        nPlus = n + 1
    sta = shape[n]
    fin = shape[nPlus]
    try:
        loopRange = getRange(sta[1], fin[1])
        for y in range(loopRange[0], loopRange[1]):#loop through y values in each vector
            if inRange(sta[1], fin[1], y) == True:#if y value is between start and finish of vector, find x coord
                xIntersect = (sta[1] - y) / (sta[1] - fin[1]) * (sta[0] - fin[0]) + sta[0]#intersect ratio multiplied against x dist between start and finish, added to x of start = x intersect
                invertMap[int(xIntersect)][y] = not invertMap[int(xIntersect)][y]#if a line intersects it, invert the intersect boolean (so if two lines intersect at that pixel, it stays false, three lines true etc)
    except:
        print("sta, fin = ", sta[1], fin[1])
#loop through pixels in y direction, then x, if pixel has invert property True, invert fill colour
map = numpy.zeros((res,res), dtype=numpy.uint8)
for y in range(res):
    colour = 0
    for x in range(res):
        if invertMap[x][y] == True:
            colour = 255 - colour
        map[x][y] = colour
return(map)
```

Any chance anyone has a clue as to what is going on?

Comment: Print out intermediate images of your results in progress.  See where they start to go wrong.  Insert more print statements to track that operation.  Break calculations into intermediate parts and track those, if necessary.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Seems like a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood how you wanted to do it, since I'm not familiar with numpy, but I think a solution much simpler like this could do the trick:

```
def invert_colors(map):
    inside = False
    for x in range(len(_map)):
        for y in range(len(_map[0])):
            if map[x][y].color == 255:
                inside = not inside
                continue
            map[x][y].color = 255 if inside else 0
```

This input :

```
map = [
    [0, 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ],
    [0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
    [0, 255, 0  , 0  , 255],
    [0, 255, 0  , 0  , 255],
    [0, 255, 255, 255, 255]
      ]
```

produces this output :

```
  [
[0, 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ],
[0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
[0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
[0, 255, 255, 255, 255],
[0, 255, 255, 255, 255]
  ]
```